# How exactly do the jspInit() and other methods work on JSP with Glassfish 4.0?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am new to JSP. This is my simple JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.Date"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%!public void jspInit() {
        System.out.println("Init called!");
    }%>
    <h3>Hello World!</h3>
    <br />
    <%
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            out.print(i + " ");
        out.println("èéòçàù<br/>");
    %>
    <b>The time right now is: <%=new Date()%></b>
    <%
        if (request.getParameter("name") != null) {
            session.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));
            application.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));
        }
    %>
    <br />
    <b>The name that was set for request is: <%=request.getParameter("name")%></b>
    <br />
    <b>The name that was set for session is: <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></b>
    <br />
    <b>The name that was set for application is: <%=application.getAttribute("name")%></b>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

The `jspInit()` method is called every time my page is opened. Shouldn't it be called only the first time the page is opened? And can somebody please tell me what are the other JSP methods and how do they work? I can't find precise information on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use deployment descriptor for setting mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Index/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When you opening the page via direct name(index.jsp) the .jsp file isn't working correctly and jspInit() is calling every time when you open the page. But when you open page using url pattern(Index), the page works correctly.